# How can I specify the default Media Type for the Swagger in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

How can I specify the default Media Type for the Swagger in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

E.g. I have three choices of the Media Type. And I want the default to be `application/json`, and not the `text/plain`. How can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the attribute to your api controller:

```
 [Produces("application/json")]
```

Comment: Thanks. Just have found another related thread: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1566.

Answer (score 12):

You can configure this globally in your application in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
    })
```

or for multiple response types:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json", "text/plain", "text/json"));
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

To extend upon [@feihoa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302739/3025856) in order to have a complete solution:

Add [the `[Produces]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to your API Controller with two parameters:

1. The default media type (i.e. `application/json`)
2. An array of strings for additional media types you want to accept (i.e. `plain/text` and/or `plain/json` and/or `application/xml`)

```cs
[Produces("application/json", new string[] { "text/plain", "text/json" })]
```

Comment: Or more simply `[Produces("application/json", "text/plain", "text/json")]`

Answer (score 1):

Decorating the API Controller with [Consumes("application/json")] solves the problem.
The microsoft asp.net core documentation states that the [Produces] filter:

Forces all actions within the controller to **return** JSON-formatted responses for POCOs (Plain Old CLR Objects) or ObjectResult and its derived types.

[Consumes] allows the API to accept json.
also see https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-produces-and-consumes-attribute-in-mvc-6/