# NetCore6: SwaggerUI: output as JSON instead of string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I tried to enable compression of response as described on [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76559312) and it worked, my output per Chrome reduced from 4.9 MiB to 700 KiB

[image: uncompressed plain/text]

[image: compressed plain/text]

And the SwaggerUI output looks like `JSON` (JSON/color formatting is disabled in config for performance reasons):

[image: compressed plain/text JSON]

Now I tried to follow the advice from [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72367887/2334520) and set my output from `text/plain` to `application/json` and it compressed even more (I don't know why to be honest):

[image: compressed application/json]

However now the `SwaggerUI` output looks like a `string` instead of a `JSON`:

[image: compressed application/json string]

On the programming consumer side all these variants behave identically, so I don't have a problem there but I would like to be able to copy the `SwaggerUI` output for test reasons and I have not found a way to make it JSON again.

**Edit:**

I configured the `application/json` output as such

```
builder.Services
  .AddControllers(options =>
  {
    options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
  })
```

The response is produced this way:

```
  public class JsonActionResult<T> : IActionResult
  {
      private readonly T _value;

      private readonly HttpStatusCode _statusCode;

      public JsonActionResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value)
      {
          _statusCode = statusCode;
          _value = value;
      }

      public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
      {
          var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_value, _serializerSettings);

          var objectResult = new ObjectResult(json)
          {
              StatusCode = (int)_statusCode,
          };

          await objectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
      }
  }
```

this is probably the root cause for the string confusion:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_value, _serializerSettings)
```

But I don't know how else to get the `NewtonSoft JSON serializer settings` in there.

Comment: If you want the response to be minimal in size, the goal was achieved. If you want easier to read debug JSON, switch it back as needed. What is the issue?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan I want the SwaggerUI output be formatted as JSON. Also I don't know why application/json compresses more than three times better than plain/text because in the end JSON is just plain text.

Comment: With `[Produces("application/json")]`, either applied to each method individually or applied globally as in the answer you linked, that would produce proper JSON if you were returning an object, e.g. `return Ok(result);`, so something is wrong in the method. Please post the method implementation for the endpoint above.

Comment: " I want the SwaggerUI output be formatted as JSON. " and you stated it can be done by changing the output by the user. How is this a problem?

Comment: @madreflection I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: @ΩmegaMan no the output cannot be changed by the user, at least I don't know where/how?

Comment: The response body shown is `json` but in text form (Not an issue IMHO). What is the issue? Do you not want to send `json`? The web site dictates what format the data will be returned such as `application/json`. Put the appropriate attributes on the endpoint (as per @madreflection above) that dictates what should be sent out data wise and send that type of data out. The swagger UI is a developer's tool that is not intended to be used in Production. Call your endpoint using a tool like postman, requesting the appropriate data type and verify if the data returned is what is expected.

Comment: No, that's not what I asked for. That's a custom result object, not an endpoint method. You shouldn't need that class, anyway. That was necessary in the early days (pre-Core) because JSON support was immature. You should return `_value` wrapped in an `OkObjectResult`. It's as simple as `return Ok(_value);` (with a return type of `IActionResult`).

Comment: @ΩmegaMan "but in text form" which means you can't directly put it in a text file because it's not just the leading and trailing  `"` but also the `\r\n` that is in plain text instead of the actual control characters.

Comment: @madreflection we have a few NewtonSoft serializer settings for excample `DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc`. How would I go about it with `OkObjectResult`?

Comment: Or you could configure JSON.NET as the default serializer and skip the custom result object... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290811/how-to-use-newtonsoft-json-as-default-in-asp-net-core-web-api

Comment: @madreflection that's not really an option because the webservices have been running for a few years in `net472` with `NewtonSoft` and we've just recently migrated to `net6.0` and discovered a bit of differences between those two and went to great lengths to ensure that the output is identical to the previous one to ensure compatibility.

Comment: The point of using `AddNewtonsoftJson` is that it makes ASP.NET Core serialize using JSON.NET just like it did in the older versions, so you don't have to write any code to get that compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took [madreflection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394572/madreflection)'s advice [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189020/netcore6-swaggerui-output-as-json-instead-of-string#comment136077780_77189020) and also got additional input from [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58103218/2334520) and changed the `IActionResult` code from

```
var json = JsonHelper.SerializeToJson(_value);

var objectResult = new ObjectResult(json)
{
    StatusCode = (int)_statusCode,
};
```

to

```
var objectResult = new ObjectResult(_value)
{
    StatusCode = (int)_statusCode,
};
```

and to adjust my DateTimeHandling problem, I extended

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
    })
    .AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
    {
        var converters = jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters;
        converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
        converters.Add(new NullableDateTimeConverter());
    });
```

with the converter codes:

```
internal sealed class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader
        , Type typeToConvert
        , JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var text = reader.GetString();
        var result = ToDateTime(text);
        return result;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer
        , DateTime value
        , JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var text = ToString(value);
        writer.WriteStringValue(text);
    }

    internal static DateTime ToDateTime(string text)
    {
        var timestamp = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
            ? XmlConvert.ToDateTime(text, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc)
            : new DateTime().ToUniversalTime();
        return timestamp;
    }

    internal static string ToString(DateTime value)
        => XmlConvert.ToString(value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
}

internal sealed class NullableDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime?>
{
    public override DateTime? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader
        , Type typeToConvert
        , JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var text = reader.GetString();
        var timestamp = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
            ? DateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(text)
            : (DateTime?)null;
        return timestamp;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer
        , DateTime? value
        , JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var text = value.HasValue
            ? DateTimeConverter.ToString(value.Value)
            : null;
        writer.WriteStringValue(text);
    }
}
```

Et voilà:

[image: Properly formatted]